# headMeta() in zend_view returns nothing, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pimcore

I'm using Pimcore with the Zend Framework. In my header view, I output this:

`<?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?>`

The output is blank.
Instead I've changed it to this:

`<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $this->document->description ?>" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $this->document->keywords ?>" />`

That works fine. The issue here is that I want to use zend correctly and I feel that this is probably not the most ideal approach.

Can anyone coach me on the correct way of performing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Boostrap.php` file you need to init the `head` with values like this:

```
$view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8')
                 ->appendName('description', 'mySite');

$view->headTitle()->setSeparator ('-')->headTitle('myPage');

$view->doctype('HTML4_STRICT');
```

This code belongs in the `_initViewHelpers` function. Then you can call it in the `<head>`:

```
<?php
    echo $this->doctype ();
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <?php 
        echo $this->headMeta();
        echo $this->headTitle();
    ?>
//...
```

Comment: Where does one find the bootstrap.php file. How long have you been working with Pimcore for? Is there a forum or community I can go to for help? so far i've been posting comments in the confluence wiki

Comment: I don't know how to do that in pimcore, either there is a configuration file somewhere or you do it somewhere in the backend because its a cms. My answer shows you how to hardcode it in the bootstrap which is located in the application folder of your project

Comment: Seems like there aren't that many pimcore developers out there, I wonder why it enjoys a reputation of wide use...